# Decoding Java's JSON Unicode values with PHP

Tags: java, php, api, unicode, linkedin-api

I had experienced different JSON encoded value for the same string depending on the language used in the past. Since the APIs were used in closed environment (no 3rd parties allowed), we made a compromise and all our Java applications are manually encoding Unicode characters. LinkedIn's API is returning "corrupted" values, basically the same as our Java applications. I've already posted a [question](http://developer.linkedin.com/message/7025) on their forum, the reason I am asking it here as well is quite simple; sharing is caring :) This question is therefore partially connected with LinkedIn, but mostly trying to find an answer to the general encoding problem described below.

As you can see, my last name contains a letter `ž`, which should be `\u017e` but Java (or LinkedIn's API for that matter) returns `\u009e` with JSON and nothing with XML response. PHP's `json_decode()` ignores it and my last name becomes Kurida.

After an investigation, I've found `ž` apparently has two representations, [9e](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9e/index.htm) and [17e](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/17e/index.htm). What exactly is going on here? Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U+009E is a usually-invisible control character and not an acceptable alternative representation for `ž`.

The *byte* 0x9E represents the character `ž` in Windows code page 1252. That byte, if decoded using ISO-8859-1, would turn into U+009E.

(The confusion comes from the fact that if you write `&#x009E;` in an HTML page, the browser doesn't actually give you character U+009E, as you might expect, but converts it to U+017E. The same is true of all the character references 0080–009F: they get changed as if the numbers referred to cp1252 bytes instead of Unicode characters. This is utterly bizarre and wrong behaviour, but all the major browsers do it so we're stuck with it now. Except in proper XHTML served as XML, since that has to follow the more sensible XML rules.)

Looking at the forum page, the JSON-reading is clearly not wrong: your name is registered as being “David Kurid[U+009E]a”. However that data has got into their system needs looking at.

Comment: Thank you for a very descriptive answer. LinkedIn got back saying they have a bug in their API, based on your answer, we may have a similiar one in our Java apps as well. I could have sworn we are using UTF-8 all over the place. Well, double check it is :) Thanks again.